# How can I stop part of a python program from running, but have the rest execute regularly?

Tags: python, multiprocess

I am trying to terminate a function prematurely but have the rest of my program run normally. I am not allowed to change the behavior of the function.

I have tried placing the function into a process (using the multiprocessing python library) and terminate that process. However, I have been getting an error from the signal library. I believe that this is because the terminate() function does not terminate the child processes of the parent process, but I am not sure.

Any help on how I can fix this or new approaches would be greatly appreciated.

```
def train(self):
    import reaver as rvr
    env = rvr.envs.SC2Env(map_name='MoveToBeacon')
    agent = rvr.agents.A2C(env.obs_spec(), env.act_spec(), rvr.models.build_fully_conv, rvr.models.SC2MultiPolicy, n_envs=4)
    agent.run(env)


def run(self):
    import multiprocessing
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.train, args=())
    p.start()

    import time
    time.sleep(120)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    print("hello) # agent.run(env) shouldn't be running here
```

run()

The following is the error message that I receive. Ideally, the output would be just be "hello".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "signal.py", line 42, in <module>
    trainingHelper.run()
  File "signal.py", line 34, in run
    p.terminate()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 116, in terminate
    self._popen.terminate()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 56, in terminate
    os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGTERM'
```

Comment: I'm using version 3.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you called your file signal.py, try renaming it and your code should work. The signal is also a python module which is in conflict.